# PWN PI Setup Error: LIBKMOD Error c:554

Tags: filesystem, mount

I keep on getting this file system mounting error on my Raspberry Pi 2 running PWNPI.

The error message seems to be coming from a process called libkmod.

The exact error message is:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.1.17-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
```

***Update

Is there anything else that I need to add, or something else?

Comment: What is the error? Without knowing what the error is, it will be rather difficult to help you. Please edit your question, and include the error message.